# how to combine two C++ projects, one used CMake and the other is VS containing some nuget packages?

Tags: c++, cmake, nuget, nuget-package, onnxruntime

I'm working on a source code which is a big project presented by CMake. I want to add some functions to this big project to do some ANN inference in it. For this reason, I need some libraries such as ONNX and OpenCV. These libraries are in NuGet packages. I tried the complete process in a separate Visual Studio solution but I couldn't find any way to add NuGet packages to Cmake projects. How can I use these libraries?
Is it possible to unpackage the NuGet package and use the inner .dll or .lib files?

Comment: When you consume the packages with VS, it should create a folder called 'packages' in the solution.  This folder will contain the NuGet packages.  Within those folders will be all files necessary to consume the library.  You should be able to copy the required files and add them to your project.  Not sure this is the best way, but it should be possible to wrestle through it.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the NuGet packages that I have created and/or consumed using MSVC native code applications, all of the files necessary to consume the package become resident in the consuming solution. (For .Net projects, the process is a little different.)

When a package is added to a project it gets downloaded to a folder within the solution called "packages".  Within the packages folder will be sub-folders that contain the distributable format of the NuGet packages that the projects in the solution are consuming.

Within the sub-folders for each NuGet package are the distributed files.  These files contain any header files, .lib files, .dll files, etc. that are to be consumed by the user of the package.

There will typically be a file with the extension .targets somewhere in the folder structure for the package.  This file exposes the project information for the package.  This file gets merged into the project file of the project that is consuming the package.  It directs the build process by adding the proper include paths for the compiler and linker, among other things that may be required by the consuming project.

Also in the folder structure will be any headers required to use the package, and any object code required to link the package into the solution.  Many packages are header only, and may not require anything other than for the headers to be transferred to your Make file project.

It should be possible to create a VS solution with a project that consumes the packages you are interested in.  Then browse through the packages folder and examine what files are there, and reverse-engineer the .targets file to see what files are needed by the compiler and linker, etc.

There may be some other way to automate this process, but it would certainly be feasible to extract the required information from a VS project that consumes the packages.